Will an MVC 5 .Net 4.8 Solution run with a Ionic Capacitor wrapper?
I have a PWA and was wondering if Ionic Capacitor will work for wrapping this PWA? I've never worked with Capacitor or Cordova and thought I'd ask for some wisdom and direction before wasting a lot of time. The Dev Environment for this solution is VS2019.
As I understand it only installable through npm? Thank you so much for your help and feedback.

According to the docs, yes.

Capacitor has first-class support for Progressive Web Apps, making it easy to build an app that runs natively on iOS and Android, but also on the web as a mobile web app or "Progressive Web App."

